# is it possible in future to buy ADA directly?

Tags: plutus, wallet

out of curiosity, is it possible to buy/Withdraw fiat ADA directly from ADA wallet, stack,lend and bypass any existing exchanges to avoid expensive fees ?

Comment: Not currently possible for any currency.  All currency conversions require an exchange or broker.  Questions that ask for predictions are also not appropriate as they require speculation rather than facts in most cases.  If they can be answered with facts, they become obsolete over time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the questions about the future of Cardano can't be effectively addressed on this site and would be better addressed directly to the Cardano Team on their [forum](https://forum.cardano.org/). This site is not operated by the Cardano organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LocalBitcoin.com](https://localbitcoins.com/instant-bitcoins/?action=buy&amount=1&currency=ADA&country_code=US&online_provider=ALTCOIN_ADA&find-offers=Search) might have some options.